# VPN Server Port forwarding

Tags: vpn, port, forwarding

I got a VPN client 192.168.0.9 which is connected via a my home VPN server 192.168.0.12.
(Most of my LAN clients are connected via 192.168.0.12 to use VPN).

I'd like to port forward from WAN via my home router 192.168.0.1 port 123456 to my VPN Client 192.168.0.9

All is working fine if I use 192.168.0.1 as gateway for 192.168.0.9.
It doesn't work if I use 192.168.0.12 as gateway.

Iptable on VPN 192.168.0.12 looks like this.

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables --flush
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -m comment --comment "In from LAN" -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -m comment --comment "loopback" -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -m comment --comment "loopback" -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -m comment --comment "In from LAN" -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -o tun0 -m comment --comment "Out to VPN" -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 1198 -m comment --comment "openvpn" -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 123 -m comment --comment "ntp" -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p UDP --dport 67:68 -m comment --comment "dhcp" -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 53 -m comment --comment "dns" -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -m comment --comment "LAN out to VPN" -j ACCEPT

I have tried to add these rules 

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.12 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.9
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.12 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.9
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 123456  -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.9:123456
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 123456  -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.9:123456
```

Then I forwarded port 123456 from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.12 but it's not working.

Any help please ?

Comment: First of all, the valid range for a tcp/udp port is 0-65535.

Comment: i think you should Google for howto nat, in any case this question does not belong to a business related environment. Referring to the superuser site instead.